# How to capture group in Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture `customer.name` from `hello @customer.name` from the end of the text string.

However, I can't seem to get the `@` character out of it. It gives `@customer.name`.

Right now my regex expression is:

```
@([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.match` method of the string. The result will be `null` if there was no match with the given regex, otherwise it will be an array where:

- The first element is the entire matched string, `@customer.name` in your case
- The remaining elements are each capture group. You have one capture group so that would end up in the 1st index. In your case this will be `customer.name`, the string you want.

See this snippet. Your regex already looks correct, you just need to pull only the capture group from it instead of the entire matched string.

```js
const str = "hello @customer.name"
const reg = /@([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)$/;

const match = str.match(reg)
console.log(match)
console.log("Matched string:", match[0]);
console.log("First capture group:", match[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex works fine, here's some code to use it to access your capture group using the regex .exec function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

```js
let testString ='hello @customer.name',
    pattern = /@([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)$/,
    match = pattern.exec(testString);
    
console.log(match[1]); // abc
```